# How to View and Hide Password for all rows of the table

Tags: javascript, php, html, password-encryption

[image: Table from the database]The show password function only works on the first row of the entry and is not working on the next entries/rows. The items are displayed by php through the database using foreach. how will the show/hide password work for all entries? any ideas?? I have the code as follows:

Html:

```
<td data-title="Password"><input id="viewPass" type="password" value="<?php echo $item["password"]; ?>" readonly/></td>
<button type="button" id="viewPswd" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
<script src="js/showPass.js"></script>
```

Javascript:

```
 var myButton = document.getElementById('viewPswd'),
  myInput = document.getElementById('viewPass');
  myButton.onclick = function () {

      'use strict';

      if (this.id === 'viewPswd') {
          myInput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
          this.textContent = 'Hide';

      } else {

           myInput.setAttribute('type', 'password');

           this.id = 'viewPswd';
      }
  };
```

Comment: The issue is `Id` selectors works for a single element. You have to use `class` selector here.

Comment: i have tried it but it ain't working.

Comment: Simple: **Don't EVER show the password.** It should not be possible to read/decode the password at all, anywhere in your application or database.

Comment: I don't see a problem in my code. u just assign name attr to your btn and txt box in ur php foreach loop. and use my js.

Comment: given the comments under an answer that it is "not working", I feel that the question is missing essential code. This seems to be db-related, and that code should be included in an update to the question, as well as more HTML.

Comment: @AravindhGopi - yes your code is working.. Sorry about that, i forgot to include the name attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to work with multiple buttons and textboxes you have to assign 
 a common `name` or `class` or indivdual `id`.

You can't assign same id to all elements.

Here i used `name` attribute

```js
var myButton = document.getElementsByName('dynamic');
var myInput = document.getElementsByName('viewPass');
myButton.forEach(function(element, index){
  element.onclick = function(){
     'use strict';

      if (myInput[index].type == 'password') {
          myInput[index].setAttribute('type', 'text');
          element.firstChild.textContent = 'Hide';
          element.firstChild.className = "";

      } else {
           myInput[index].setAttribute('type', 'password');
           element.firstChild.textContent = '';
            element.firstChild.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open";
      }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<td data-title="Password">
<input name="viewPass" type="password" value="abcd" readonly/></td>


<button type="button" id="" class="btn btn-default" name="dynamic"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
<br>
<td data-title="Password">
<input name="viewPass" type="password" value="watha" readonly/></td>

<button type="button" id="" class="btn btn-default" name="dynamic"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
<br>

<td data-title="Password">
<input name="viewPass" type="password" value="xyz" readonly/></td>

<button type="button" id="" class="btn btn-default" name="dynamic"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
```

Comment: the next rows. it only works on the first row but on next rows, the button does not work.

Comment: Thanks so much!! your code is working great!! i just forgot to include the name on my input. sorry about that..

Comment: im sorry.. lol. and i am pissed why i can't put an upvote. why only check. stockoverflow says that i need to be on 15 reputation. sad.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyways. u were really helpful.. Kudos.

Comment: Thanks for that. haha. i now put an upvote to ur answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to update the element so that next time you can check if its shown or hidden. You can use custom attribute like state.

```
var myButton = document.getElementById('viewPswd'),
  myInput = document.getElementById('viewPass');
  myButton.onclick = function () {

      'use strict';
            if(this.getAttribute('state') == 'hidden'){
          myInput.setAttribute('type', 'text');
          this.textContent = 'Hide';
          this.setAttribute('state', 'shown');

      } else {
           myInput.setAttribute('type', 'password');
                    this.setAttribute('state', 'hidden');
          this.textContent = 'Show';
      }
  }
```

PFB working example for you : https://jsfiddle.net/8mfhpy2q/

Note that this will work for one button per page as we are using ID attribute here. If there are multiple password fields and buttons, this will be different.